# pandas add row count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have a df like:

```
    Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D
0   PakA    1223    435     989
1   BanT    343     23      2323.1
```

what I need it:

```
    Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D
0   PakA    1223    435     989
1   BanT    343     23      2323.1
2   Total   1698    458     3312.1
```

What I tried:

```
 df.loc['Total'] = df_new.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
```

But this gave me NaN

Answer (score 1):

First ensure that the target column is your index:

```
# ensure Col A is the index
df = df.set_index('Col A')

# assign the total
df.loc['Total'] = df.select_dtypes('number').sum()
# or
# df.loc['Total'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)

# eventually reset the index
df = df.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Col A   Col B  Col C   Col D
0   PakA  1223.0  435.0   989.0
1   BanT   343.0   23.0  2323.1
2  Total  1566.0  458.0  3312.1
```

###### alternative if you have a range index:

```
idx = len(df)
df.loc[idx] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
df.loc[idx, 'Col A'] = 'Total'
```

Comment: I get the last row like this now: `2  Total  NaN NaN NaN`

Comment: I think those column are of type str, how could they be converted to float?

Comment: I tried to change the type like this: `df.astype({col: float for col in df.columns[1:]})` but did not have any effect

Comment: And `cols = list(df.columns[1:]) ; df[cols] = df[cols].astype(float)`?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `df.to_dict()` if you still have issues?